# nativescript won't install on MacOS

Tags: macos, npm, nativescript

i've followed the install instructions on nativescripts websites to the command 'sudo npm install -g nativescript' and i get this error message

```
    sudo npm i -g nativescript
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: abbrev@1.1.0 (node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.abbrev.DELETE'

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ansi-regex.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

any and all help would be apperciated

Comment: P.S. Everything else went as it should have and installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo npm cache clean
sudo npm install nativescript -g
```

If that doesn't work, try uninstalling first:

```
sudo npm uninstall nativescript -g
sudo npm install nativescript -g
```

And if that doesn't work, delete the native script directory and reinstall:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript
sudo npm install nativescript -g
```

One of these should solve it.